# Is there an alternative of \arraycolsep for cases environment?

Tags: cases

I have this problem:

[image]

I can control the space in `array` environment with `\arraycolsep`, but it doesn't work in `cases` environment. Is there an alternative of \arraycolsep for cases environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.2pt}
$\begin{array}{cl}
    4x-5y =23&  \scriptstyle |\cdot 3\\
    6x+7y=-9&  \scriptstyle |\cdot (-2)
\end{array}$

$\begin{cases}
    4x-5y =23&  \scriptstyle |\cdot 3\\
    6x+7y=-9&  \scriptstyle |\cdot (-2)
\end{cases}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `systeme`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\systeme{
  4x - 5y = 23 @ \scriptstyle|\cdot3,
  6x + 7y = -9 @ \scriptstyle|\cdot(-2)
}
\]

\[
\syscodeextracol{\hspace{0.5em}$}{$}
\systeme{
  4x - 5y = 23 @ \scriptstyle|\cdot3,
  6x + 7y = -9 @ \scriptstyle|\cdot(-2)
}
\]

\[
\syscodeextracol{\hspace{0.5em}$\scriptstyle|\cdot}{$}
\systeme{
  4x - 5y = 23 @ 3,
  6x + 7y = -9 @ (-2)
}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `\syscodeextracol` command can go in the preamble and affect every `\systeme` in the document. In the last example I show how you can refine the customization.

The default separation is `\hspace{1.5em}`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Systeme with \syscodeextracol is perfect!